# How do I make a box popup on hover over an unordered list, Also position it correctly and make responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have and unordered list with each item in a box/div, I want to popup a large box/div with an image and Extra details about the list item. I want to make it popup in a manner where it will be centered in X & Y direction to the list item box.

I tried it with a position absolute, but it is not aligning properly as I needed and some of it crops out of the page. I also want it responsive. How do I position it correctly?

This is what I tried:

```css
.skills {
    height:200px;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin:auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.skills li {
    border: 2px solid black;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: .8rem;
    border-radius: .9rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.skill-detail {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: lightcyan;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px;
}

li:hover .skill-detail {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="skills">
    <li>
        <div class="skill-detail">CSS gives design, colors and styles to a webpage.</div>
        CSS
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="skill-detail">Bootstrap is a CSS framework used for making responsive websites.
        </div>
        Bootstrap
    </li>
<ul>
```

I want the popup to be centered to the list item box. Also want to adjust automatically on small devices.